# How can I get the XML file from Twitter API user_timeline

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am new with the twitter API, How can I get the XML format from my twitter account?
I was trying https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/myusername.xml
I am changing the "myusername" to my actual username but it's showing bad access. ALso, I'm going to fetch from XCode.
Thanks for helping

Comment: None of this has to do with Xcode. Is this iOS or OS X? Objective-C? Update your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter doesn't provide XML format with the 1.1 API, they used to offer XML on version 1.

To see your own timeline the URL you need to call is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json 
Before that link works as expected you will need to authenticate yourself via OAuth using application keys you must generate at https://dev.twitter.com/ and following the instructions here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request
You should look for a library in objective-c that helps you to do this in a simpler way, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries